# unable to upload video on flickr ios

Tags: ios, flickr

i am developing an `iOS` app wherein i want to upload videos and photos on `flickr`. i have completed with the photo part but i am not able to `upload videos` on `flickr`. my code on selecting the video file is opening it where as i want to upload it on `flickr`.anyone knowing the and please do reply.this is my piece of code

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        NSString *moviePath = (NSString*)[[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
        // NSLog(@"%@",moviePath);
        // NSURL *videoUrl=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
        }
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

In above code you just picking the video file there is no code of uploading video or any flickr api used in it. So try to upload video in such a manner :-

```
NSString *uploadSig = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@api_key%@auth_token%@", secret, api_key, auth_token] MD5];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/upload/"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------7d44e178b0434"];

[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_key\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", api_key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"auth_token\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", auth_token] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_sig\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", uploadSig] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"photo.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:imageData];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

May this helps you. If Any question you can ask in comments.

Comment: It's just a method of encryption. Defined in such a way.

Comment: On flickr api documentation try to find out , is it neccessary to encrpt the key or not. If not then remove md5.

Comment: after adding the code my video is getting added to my simulator gallery.

Comment: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\n<rsp stat=\"fail\">\n\t<err code=\"98\" msg=\"Invalid auth token\" />\n</rsp>\n" 

I am getting this error